# How to split and insert a php array with some identical values into two mysql relational tables with unique values

Tags: php, mysql, unique, distinct, relational

I've got this php $array :

```
usr_id | value 1 | value 2 | value 3

1      |    a    |    b    |   c
2      |    a    |    b    |   c
7      |    d    |    e    |   f
8      |    a    |    e    |   f
```

And I want to split it into two relational tables with unique combined values:

TABLE 1 > values

```
id | value1 | value2 | value3

1  | a      | b      | c
2  | d      | e      | f
3  | a      | e      | f
```

TABLE 2 > relations

```
id | usr_id | values_id 

1  |    1    | 1
2  |    2    | 1
3  |    7    | 2
4  |    8    | 3
```

What is the easiest way to do that ?

Thank you a lot in advance !

Comment: its not clear where the `2/relation` values are coming from

Comment: sorry... in the table "relation" id is a new auto-increment id, usr_id comes from the php array, values_id is the inserted auto-increment id coming from the inserted unique "values" in the "values" table ! thank you

Comment: For me it is the same, i'll be doing this operation only one time when importing my php data in mysql!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to make two passes over the php array. Once to create the values table and then again to create the relations table. there is probably a way to do it with only one pass but since you say you will only do this 1x maybe it isn't necc to optimize it any further.

```
(pcode)
create table values ( id int auto_increment, value1 int, value2 int value3 int, 
    primary key(id), unique key( value1, value2, value3 ));    

foreach( $array as $val )
{
   $q = $pdo->prepare( "insert ignore into values ( value1, value2, value3 ) values (?,?,?) " )
   $q->bindParam( $val->value1 );
   ...
}
```

Then make a second pass where you select the appropriate value from `values` and insert into the relations table.

```
(pcode)
foreach( $array as $val )
{
   $ret = $pdo->do( "select id from values where value1 = ?, value2 = ?, value3 = ?" );
   ( build the query )
   $row = $ret->fetch();
   $id = $row->id;

   (now insert into relations )
   $pdo->prepare( "insert into relations (usr_id, values_id ) values ( ?, ? )" );
   $pdo->bindParam( 1, $id );
   $pdo->bindParam( 2, $val->usr_id );
   $pdo->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Will "unique (value1, value2, value3)" create an unique "combined" value ? Because some values can be identical but not the whole set.I just edited a little bit my php array to be more clear : for usr_id 8 value1 can be "a". Thank you !